# jQuery Change Html Content

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following HTML5 content:

```
<section contenteditable="true" id="editable" class="ui-selectee ui-selected">
<span>something</span>
<span>something</span>
<span>something</span>
</selection>
```

I have a toggle function that turns on edit mode. I want to make the contenteditable="true" or contenteditable="false" on that toggle function.
I've it would be easy if I would have to change a class or ID. Ive tryed to .html the #edit or append but I was unable to.

Any tips on changing contenteditable="true" to contenteditable="false" ?
Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

....

```
$('selector').click(function(){
  $('#editable').attr('contenteditable', false);
});
```

You can use the `if-else` condition to check its current status and set the required on accordingly using:

```
$('#editable').attr('contenteditable', false); // or true
```

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to use the [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function.

To set the value to true:

```
attr("contenteditable", "true");
```